# c++ thread overhead

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, c++11

I'm playing around with threads in C++, in particular using them to parallelize a map operation.

Here's the code:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double multByTwo(double x){
  return x*2;
}

double doJunk(double x){
  return cos(pow(sin(x*2),3));
}

template <typename T>
void map(T* data, int n, T (*ptr)(T)){
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    data[i] = (*ptr)(data[i]);
}

template <typename T>
void parallelMap(T* data, int n, T (*ptr)(T)){
  int NUMCORES = 3;
  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
  for (int i=0; i<NUMCORES; i++)
    threads.push_back(std::thread(&map<T>, data + i*n/NUMCORES, n/NUMCORES, ptr));
  for (std::thread& t : threads)
    t.join();
}

int main()
{
  int n = 1000000000;
  double* nums = new double[n];
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    nums[i] = i;

  std::cout<<"go"<<std::endl;

  clock_t c1 = clock();

  struct timespec start, finish;
  double elapsed;

  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);

  // also try with &doJunk
  //parallelMap(nums, n, &multByTwo);
  map(nums, n, &doJunk);

  std::cout << nums[342] << std::endl;

  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &finish);

  printf("CPU elapsed time is %f seconds\n", double(clock()-c1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

  elapsed = (finish.tv_sec - start.tv_sec);
  elapsed += (finish.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0;

  printf("Actual elapsed time is %f seconds\n", elapsed);
}
```

With `multByTwo` the parallel version is actually slightly slower (1.01 seconds versus .95 real time), and with doJunk its faster (51 versus 136 real time). This implies to me that

1. the parallelization is working, and
2. there is a REALLY large overhead with declaring 
   new threads. Any thoughts as to why the overhead is so large, and how I can avoid it?

Comment: Note that this isn't necessarily specific to *native threads in C++*, but the *implementation* and the compiler you use. As such, it's hard to give a definitive answer.

Comment: What hardware are you running this code on? Processor type and number of sockets? RAM? OS? Compiler version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just a guess: what you're likely seeing is that the `multByTwo` code is so fast that you're achieving memory saturation. The code will never run any faster no matter how much processor power you throw at it, because it's already going as fast as it can get the bits to and from RAM.

Comment: This looks correct. The OP has an 8GB dataset. 8 GB in 1.01 seconds sounds about right for a high-end Nehalem or a low-end Sandy Bridge generation processor.

Answer (score 3):

You did not specify the hardware that you test your program nor the compiler version and the operating system. I did try your code on our four-socket Intel Xeon systems under 64-bit Scientific Linux with `g++` 4.7 compiled from source.

First on an older Xeon X7350 system I got the following timings:

`multByTwo` with `map`

```
CPU elapsed time is 6.690000 seconds
Actual elapsed time is 6.691940 seconds
```

`multByTwo` with `parallelMap` on 3 cores

```
CPU elapsed time is 7.330000 seconds
Actual elapsed time is 2.480294 seconds
```

The parallel speedup is 2.7x.

`doJunk` with `map`

```
CPU elapsed time is 209.250000 seconds
Actual elapsed time is 209.289025 seconds
```

`doJunk` with `parallelMap` on 3 cores

```
CPU elapsed time is 220.770000 seconds
Actual elapsed time is 73.900960 seconds
```

The parallel speedup is 2.83x.

Note that X7350 is from the quite old pre-Nehalem "Tigerton" family with FSB bus and a shared memory controller located in the north bridge. This is a pure SMP system with no NUMA effects.

Then I run your code on a four-socket Intel X7550. These are Nehalem ("Beckton") Xeons with memory controller integrated into the CPU and hence a 4-node NUMA system. Threads running on one socket and accessing memory located on another socket will run somewhat slower. The same is also true for a serial process that might get migrated to another socket by some stupid scheduler decision. Binding in such a system is very important as you may see from the timings:

`multByTwo` with `map`

```
CPU elapsed time is 4.270000 seconds
Actual elapsed time is 4.264875 seconds
```

`multByTwo` with `map` bound to NUMA node 0

```
CPU elapsed time is 4.160000 seconds
Actual elapsed time is 4.160180 seconds
```

`multByTwo` with `map` bound to NUMA node 0 and CPU socket 1

```
CPU elapsed time is 5.910000 seconds
Actual elapsed time is 5.912319 seconds
```

`mutlByTwo` with `parallelMap` on 3 cores

```
CPU elapsed time is 7.530000 seconds
Actual elapsed time is 3.696616 seconds
```

Parallel speedup is only 1.13x (relative to the fastest node-bound serial execution). Now with binding:

`multByTwo` with `parallelMap` on 3 cores bound to NUMA node 0

```
CPU elapsed time is 4.630000 seconds
Actual elapsed time is 1.548102 seconds
```

Parallel speedup is 2.69x - as much as for the Tigerton CPUs.

`multByTwo` with `parallelMap` on 3 cores bound to NUMA node 0 and CPU socket 1

```
CPU elapsed time is 5.190000 seconds
Actual elapsed time is 1.760623 seconds
```

Parallel speedup is 2.36x - 88% of the previous case.

(I was too impatient to wait for the `doJunk` code to finish on the relatively slower Nehalems but I would expect somewhat better performance as was in Tigerton case)

There is one caveat with NUMA binding though. If you force e.g. binding to NUMA node 0 with `numactl --cpubind=0 --membind=0 ./program` this will limit memory allocation to this node only and on your particular system the memory attached to CPU 0 might not be enough and a run-time failure will most likely occur.

As you can see there are factors, other than the overhead from creating threads, that can significantly influence your code execution time. Also on very fast systems the overhead can be too high compared to the computational work done by each thread. That's why when asking questions concerning parallel performance, one should always include as much details as possible about the hardware and the environment used to measure the performance.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple threads can only do more work in less time on a multi-core machine.

Other wise they are just taking turns in a Round-Robin fashion.

Comment: I'm not talking about 'perceived' performance and the UI.  I'm talking about real work.  If there is only one processor, only one thread can run at a time.

Comment: This is true, but how the OS assigns time to the threads make a huge difference.  I have seen this in real world with apps that I was forced to write in school (way before multi-core) that the performance was hugely increased by threading them.  Look at my answer I esplain the round robin effect, I dont use that term, but it is explained why a multi-threaded app will be given more time slices of processor time!!!

Comment: Some operating systems will steal processor time from other applications and give them to a multi-threaded app?  I didn't know that.  It seems the potential for abuse would be high.

Comment: It usually all depends on the priority assigned in the priority queue.  Again my example explained a situation where all threads and processes are held under the same priority level.  Thus when a new thread is added, it get given the same time weighting as all other processes / thread (which is 1 / totalThreadCount).  The more total threads, the smaller the time per thread, but the more for the app that has the most threads!!!  And YES, it can easily be taken advantage of!!!  Think about a multi-threaded 3D rendering app, other applications get very few cycles when 3D is processing.

Answer (score 0):

Spawning new threads can be an expensive operation depending on the platform.  The easiest way to avoid this overhead is to spawn a few threads at the launch of the program and have some sort of job queue.  I believe std::async will do this for you.

Comment: The OP is only spawning them once - and the task is fairly large `n = 1000000000`. So I don't think this is the case.

Comment: I believe the end result wll be the same, if the number of threads are less than the number returned by std::thread::hardware_concurrency()